# Is it "OObuntu" or "YOUbuntu"?

Tags: ubuntu

Please help me settle a friendly bet.

I think it's the former, but my colleague is making fun of me. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. He also thinks 'GIF' is pronounced with a *J* sound.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/34980/412264.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited, here I think off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is obviously a matter of pronunciation depending on country and dialect, can't be IMHO answered at 100%.

Comment: Answered. The OP must not lose a bet with a person pronouncing GIF with a J! :)

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak as OP, can I close it off myself? New to the platform.

Comment: @dr01 Much appreciated sir/madam!

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you!

Comment: Upvoted comment and answer. Move it anyway! Whatever site *-exchange has for that. Like: Animals Eating Homework

Comment: G in GIF is pronounced same as J in JUST ... it just does not roll off the tongue is pronounced as G in GOOGLE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ubuntu) it's the former, [úɓúːⁿtu] i.e. "oo-boon-too".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_conventions_of_the_International_Phonetic_Alphabet